# Spring Boot Too Many Redirects

Tags: spring-boot

I'm developing a simple login Form using a Thymeleaf & Spring Boot. When i try hitting the following URL in Chrome: "http://localhost:8080/login" i get an error saying "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". I've tried clearing my cache & cookies in the browser and still get the same error.

I tried disabling the default security login screen by putting the following property into my application.properties: `security.basic.enabled=false`

and added the following configuration to my SecurityConfig so any URL except "/login" and "/resources" would get authenticated:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }
```

My LoginController is strightforward:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String loadForm(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("user", new User());
            return "redirect:/login";
        }
```

Anyone have any idea's why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Controller catches and redirects to the same url:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

Also, your SecurityConfig defines this:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    .loginPage("/login")
}
```

`.loginPage()`'s javadoc says this:

> login page to redirect to if authentication is required

So, any secured request made or direct access to /login will:

- redirect to /login because of `.loginPage("/login")` in your `SecurityConfig`
- which you then catch with `@RequestMapping(value="/login"`
- then redirect to `/login` with `"redirect:/login"`
- then re-catch and redirect at will.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i tried redirecting to another URL i.e. /signin but it looks like I've the issue!

Comment: I changed the return "redirect:/login"; to just return "/login" and its rendering my view OK. However, whats still strange is that my debugger fires 3 times when i add a breakpoint before returning in my LoginController. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I thought the .permitAll() after the .loginPage("/login") would enable any user to view the login page without been authenticated?

Comment: Yes everyone can see the login, all I was saying is a secured request will be redirected to /login, which adds to the "redirect too many times".

Comment: @user676567 were you able to fix this? I am facing the same issue with not just login but all the urls.

Comment: @ASR4 I am having the same issue. Have you solved it?

Comment: @joel I have posted a question and followed the answer mentioned:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565184/how-to-pass-genericfilterbean-data-to-websecurityconfigureradapter-in-spring-boo

Comment: @ASR4 Thanks that helps lot