# How to pass GenericFilterBean data to WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to redirect http to https in my spring boot application using:

```
http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

But I am getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. The reason for this is that the load balancer converts all the https to http and directs the http to port 8082, therefore the app never seems to see the https.

I tried to fix this by adding isSecure before the http to https redirection, like this in my configuration:

```
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        //variables
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/admin/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        //hsts
        http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity()
        .includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(31536000); 

        http.addFilterBefore(new IsSecureFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

        //https compulsion
        if(!isSecureFilter.isSecure()) {
                http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        }           
    }
       //rest of the code
}
```

I am trying to use HttpServletRequestWrapper so that I can repeatedly use isSecure in WebSecurityConfiguration above through the IsSecureFilter I have created below, to prevent infinite redirects:

```
public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private boolean isSecure;

    public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        //So that other request method behave just like before
        super(request);
        this.isSecure = request.isSecure();       
    }

    //Use this method to read the request isSecure N times
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return this.isSecure;
    }  
}
```

Below is the filter that I am trying to inject in WebSecurityConfiguration, to use it's isSecure value above :

```
@Component
public class IsSecureFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private boolean isSecure;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = new RequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);

        this.isSecure = req.isSecure();

        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }

    public boolean isSecure() {
        return this.isSecure;
    }
}
```

So running the above code and putting `example.com/login` in the browser does redirect to `https://example.com/login`, but i am still getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. 
I can't understand what I am doing wrong? 
My first thoughts are:

- Can I inject the IsSecureFilter in WebSecurityConfiguration to retrieve isSecure?
- Am I adding the IsSecureFilter filter in a correct way to the configuration.
- Is the wrapper filter relationship defined correctly?

**EDIT**

**1)** I changed `http.addFilterAfter(new isSecureFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);` to `http.addFilterAfter(isSecureFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);`, still no effect.

**2)** I tried changing `http.addFilterBefore(isSecureFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);` to `http.addFilterAfter(isSecureFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);` but that still did not change anything.

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. Only one thing : why not use injected isSecureFilter instead of creating new instance for registering it before ChannelProcessingFilter. http.addFilterBefore(**isSecureFilter**, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);   I tried your code. Its working. There must be some other issue.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar so you are not being redirected in an infinite loop? I tried injecting the filter like you suggested, but still the infinite retry.

Comment: See: I tried your code but there is no problem with your code. I think its happening l because of  this : https --> loadbalancer --> http --> spring --> https --> loadbalancer --> http --> spring --> https ... and so on !!! Hence giving out too many redirects.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar I know, that is the reason for the redirects and hence the codes above. But that is not helping.

Comment: The way you are using Spring solution. it cannot help you in this.  **http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()** will simply signals the caller(eg. browser) that redirect to **https**://<URL> . It will only send http status 302 + required URL. Spring will itself not do anything. Then its the browser responsibility to respect 302 and call the application with the required URL. But in your case load balancer will interfere again and spring cannot help you with that.

Comment: BUT YES you can change request params(like URL, or any other required thing) in the filter directly and pass it in the spring filter chain or simply forward it to RequestDispatcher, just to fool it to be https. Register this filter at right place. But this way of changing http to https is not recommended.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar to let the app know that it is secure without changing the url to https, I am using the in built isSecure method, that lets the app know that even though the request url has http, it is actually a secure one (it knows that either through header or port etc).

Comment: See, Every time  a request is coming to spring (fresh or after http redirection), it will always be http request in your case. In addition to it there will always be a new instance of HttpServletRequest so using 'isSecure' flag will become pointless because it always be false.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar makes sense, any alternate solution you know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to resolve this issue. Based on investigation, since 8080 and 8082 are used to identify HTTP traffic and HTTPS traffic, some code are added to check the port number instead "isSecure" to decide whether redirect HTTP request or not. The code is like following:

```
public class IsSecureFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

private boolean isSecure;
private int port;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = new RequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    this.isSecure = req.isSecure();
    this.port = req.getLocalPort();


    System.out.println("[DEBUG] : isSecure FILTER :: " + isSecure);
    System.out.println("[DEBUG] : port FILTER :: " + port);
    System.out.println("[DEBUG] : URL :: " + req.getRequestURL());
    String url = req.getRequestURL().toString().toLowerCase();
    if(url.endsWith("/login") && url.startsWith("http:") && port == 8080){
        url = url.replace("http:", "https:");
        String queries = req.getQueryString();
        if (queries == null) {
            queries = "";
        } else {
            queries = "?" + queries;
        }
        url += queries;
        res.sendRedirect(url);
    }
    else {
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }
}

public boolean isSecure() {
    return this.isSecure;
}

public boolean setIsSecure(boolean isSecure) {
    return this.isSecure = isSecure;
}

public int getPort() {
    return port;
}

public void setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}
```

}

and remove  http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure() in WebSecurityConfiguration class.

Comment: This works for me! I moved the redirect logic to the filter itself and just added the filter in the web configuration call.